# Semitransparent triangle shape in the middle of a submit button

Tags: html, forms, css, geometry

I'm trying to make a submit button on my form look like this: http://nulaena.si/temp/triangle.jpg (a semitransparent triangle in the middle).

This is what I have at the moment: http://jsfiddle.net/ptinca/UJUAT/3/

Is this possible with CSS only? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: It would be much easier if you just used a bitmap as the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using a transparent PNG image as a background image for the submit button should work.

```
background: url(subscribe.png) transparent no-repeat;
```

**EDIT:**

To clarify, the image should have the orange background with the triangle in it, of course.

Comment: I'd like to achieve this with CSS only, if it's possible.

Comment: this can probably be done using complex css3 transforms and rotations and whatnot. but that headache can be thankfully avoided using an image.

Comment: Agree with Rodik. The CSS for such a button eventually might be closw in size to the necessary PNG file :)

Comment: I guess I'll go with an image then. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

There's a very easy way to do this that doesn't even require CSS3, but only use of css2 pseudo classes. The important changes to note are that you can't apply pseudo classes on inline elements such as inputs, so I had to change your input submit button to a button element

Here's the additional code:

```
html:
<form>
<input type="text" name="email" value="enter your email address" class="besedilo" />
<button type="submit" name="subscribe" value="subscribe" class="submit">Subscribe</button>
</form>

css:
button { position: relative; }
button:after {
content: '';
position: absolute;
top: 14px; right: 17px;
height: 0; width: 0;
border-top: solid 6px transparent;
border-left: solid 6px #fff;
border-bottom: solid 6px transparent;
}
```

Comment: I don't know what I did yesterday (I guess it was a bit late) but this isn't what I meant to achieve. You can see the result here: www.esports.si - arrow at the begining.